# Dynamic include file based on screen size not working

Tags: javascript, cookies, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a test page with the syntax below that works fine on a desktop but doesn't seem to work with mobile devises and returns a 500 internal server error. Any ideas on how I can correct this?

```html
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
var xy = navigator.appVersion;
xz = xy.substring(0,4);
document.cookie = "ScreenWidth=" + screen.width
document.cookie = "ScreenHeight=" + screen.height
// End -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%
'Declare variables
Dim strScreenWidth
Dim strScreenHeight
'Read the cookies with the width and height
strScreenWidth = Request.Cookies("ScreenWidth")
strScreenHeight = Request.Cookies("ScreenHeight")
%>
<% If strScreenWidth > 748 Then %>
  <!--#include file="alpha-inc1.asp"-->
<% Else %>
  <!--#include file="alpha-inc2.asp"-->
<% End If %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your sever log have to say about this?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: it's irrelevant what his server logs say. He's trying to do conditional includes in asp, which simply don't work that way.

Comment: My conditional includes work perfectly, as I mentioned on any desktop machine. I've used windows, Linux and in multiple browsers. Works perfect. However I'm not sure what is breaking when it comes to accessing the page on a mobile devise. If you copy and past my code and create a couple of simple include pages you will see that it at least works in the old traditional PC environment. Consequently everything has to be mobile friendly now and there is a bigger need to tailor build pages that are optimal for the end user.

Comment: My assumption is that mobile devises aren't passing along the needed information for the VBSCRIPT variable. Would that be a logical assertion? If so is there a way of accomplishing this on a mobile devise as well? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @MrTKO: you only think your conditional includes are working for desktops. Try adding some `Response.Write`-s into the include file you think isn't being used; you'll find that it *is* in fact being used.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: **It Doesn't Work That Way**. `#include` directives are processed by IIS long before any of the ASP code is run.

Longer answer: No matter how many `<%if...then%>` statements you put around your `#include` directives, the end result will be that **all** of the files will be included, because the includes are processed by IIS, not by ASP, and happen long before any of the code is so much as parsed. If you want your code to choose whether to run the code in file A vs. file B, you'll need to write your own pseudo-include process.

The simplest is to forget about conditional includes, and instead put your code into subroutines that you can call conditionally.

If you absolutely must separate out the code into separate files, what you can do is read in the contents of the appropriate file as one long string, which you can then `Execute`. This requires that the file contain 100% executable ASP code, with no `<% %>` tags or html. See [How to implement conditional includes in ASP using VBScript.](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134119/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/022504-1.shtml)

Comment: Thank you for the link and I'm reading that now. I'm still a little perplexed as to how its working if it's not suppose to. Granted it's only working on desktop machines. I just tested that code again and for the record it is only including 1 file upon the page being rendered. I can increase the list to 20 includes and it still works on a desktop machine and only includes 1 file.

Comment: My agenda is to build this clients page, which is written in VBSCRIPT and serve different content to mobile devises for a better UX. I'm needing to grab the width and/or resolution to serve optimized content.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for it only to be including 1 file. Try reversing the condition, i.e. put `alpha-inc1.asp` into the `Else`.

Comment: I run that test and inverted the files and oddly enough it still actually only displays 1 file. However at the end of the day it doesn't do what it's suppose to because it throws an error on mobile devises. It was interesting though because I've seen others say it doesn't work on other sites too but that appears to be an incorrect assertion. I'm going at it from an entirely different approach now in hopes that I can pass the screen size to my server side code and deliver different content based on that. Fingers crossed

Comment: Ok where am I going wrong with the following?

[pre]
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
var xy = navigator.appVersion;
xz = xy.substring(0,4);
document.cookie = "ScreenWidth=" + screen.width
document.cookie = "ScreenHeight=" + screen.height
// End -->
</script>
</head>
<body>





<%
Dim strInclude
Dim strScreenWidth
strScreenWidth = Request.Cookies("ScreenWidth")

If strScreenWidth > 748 Then
  strInclude = getMappedFileAsString("alpha-inc1.asp")
Else
  strInclude = getMappedFileAsString("alpha-inc2.asp")
End If

Execute strInclude
%>[code]

Comment: Ok where am I going wrong with the following?

<pre><code>
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
var xy = navigator.appVersion;
xz = xy.substring(0,4);
document.cookie = "ScreenWidth=" + screen.width
document.cookie = "ScreenHeight=" + screen.height
// End -->
</script>
</head>
<body>





<%
Dim strInclude
Dim strScreenWidth
strScreenWidth = Request.Cookies("ScreenWidth")

If strScreenWidth > 748 Then
  strInclude = getMappedFileAsString("alpha-inc1.asp")
Else
  strInclude = getMappedFileAsString("alpha-inc2.asp")
End If

Execute strInclude
%></code></pre>

Comment: @MrTKO: it sounds like you have a new question. Make sure to describe what you want to happen, and what actually happens.